# Selecting the latest row using groupby in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table entries similar as follows:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| Test_id | User_id | Attempts |
+---------+---------+----------+
|      12 |       5 |        1 |
|      13 |       5 |        1 |
|      12 |       5 |        2 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Now I want to select the elements group by `test_id` and should get the latest entry.

I tried this query:

```
$tests_took = Testresult::where('course_id', $courseId)
                        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->groupby('test_id')
                        ->orderBy('attempts', 'desc')
                        ->get();
```

When I display the result, I'm getting the first two rows only (only one row for one test_id - which I what I want.)  But instead of the last row for the test_id=12, it shows the first row. I always want the biggest attempt to be displayed.

My current output is like:

```
|      12 |       5 |        1 |
|      13 |       5 |        1 |
```

But I want this:

```
|      12 |       5 |        2 |
|      13 |       5 |        1 |
```

How can I achieve this? to get the latest row as the first array element when I use groupby or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` don't work very well together...

If you simply want the highest attempt per test_id i suggest using the `MAX()` function:

```
$tests_took = Testresult::select('test_id', 'user_id', DB::raw('MAX(attempts) AS max_attempts'))
                ->where('course_id', $courseId)
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->groupby('test_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: It still shows the first row instead of the last one.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Try `AS maxAttempts` instead of `AS attempts`. Although I thought this wouldn't make a difference maybe it does...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following lines:

```
 Testresult::select('*')
         ->join(DB::raw('(Select max(id) as last_id from Testresult group by test_id) LatestId'), function($join) {
            $join->on('Testresult.id', '=', 'LatestId.last_id');
            })
         ->orderBy('attempts', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: Is this something new regarding the accepted answer?